# How do I set Ansible python interpreter on for remote Windows host?

Tags: python, windows, ansible

Ansible fails to find a python interpreter on my remote Windows host. To try to avoid this problem, I want to dynamically tell Ansible where the interpreter on the remote host is.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
---
- name: My playbook
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: Verify python installed
    win_shell: python --version
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

  - name: Find python binary
    win_shell: (get-command python).Source
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

  - name: Set where python interpreter is
    set_fact:
      ansible_python_interpretor: "{{ result.stdout_lines[0] }}"

  - name: Create tmp directory
    file:
      path: C:\tmp
      state: directory
```

When I run this playbook, I get the following output:

```
TASK [Verify python installed] ************************************************************************************************************
changed: [<remote IP>]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<remote IP>] => {
    "msg": "Python 3.10.4\r\n"
}

TASK [Find python binary] *****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [<remote IP>]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<remote IP>] => {
    "msg": "C:\\Python310\\python.exe\r\n"
}

TASK [Set where python interpreter is] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [<remote IP>]

TASK [Create tmp directory] ***************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: No python interpreters found for host <remote IP> (tried ['python3.10', 'python3.9', 'python3.8', 'python3.7', 'python3.6',
'python3.5', '/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/libexec/platform-python', 'python2.7', 'python2.6', '/usr/bin/python', 'python'])
fatal: [<remote IP>]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Create\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"At line:4 char:21\r\n+ def _ansiballz_main():\r\n+                     ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:8 char:19\r\n+         os.getcwd()\r\n+                   ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:20 char:27\r\n+     except (AttributeError, OSError):\r\n+                           ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nAt line:22 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:22 char:30\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                              ~~~~~~~~~\r\nUnexpected token 'scriptdir' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing closing ')' in expression.\r\nAt line:22 char:39\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                       ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:40\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                        ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:29 char:7\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\nAt line:29 char:30\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                              ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nNot all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.\"\r\nAt line:10 char:1\r\n+ $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException\r\n \r\nThe expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command \r\nname, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.\r\nAt line:11 char:2\r\n+ &$exec_wrapper\r\n+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression\r\n ", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
<remote IP>              : ok=9    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I'm not sure that the interpreter's location on the remote Windows host will always be the same, so I am not sure if it is safe for me to hardcode this location.

How can I correctly tell Ansible where it can find the python interpreter on the remote Windows host?

Comment: It's because `file:` is exclusively for sane operating systems; yours has its own module, [`win_file:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/windows/win_file_module.html)

Comment: do you have a typon on `ansible_python_interpretor` -> `ansible_python_interpreter` ?

Comment: @shane did you find how to set the path? i added this in my host file
ansible_python_interpreter=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this problem (I think that you can't).

I came here with the same question and later I found this from the official Ansible documentation:

- [Can I run Python modules on Windows hosts? No](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_faq.html#can-i-run-python-modules-on-windows-hosts)

  (*You are reading the latest (stable) community version of the Ansible documentation.*)

So I think that we're screwed.